# website not indexed

Tags: google-search, noindex, google-xml-sitemaps

I have a problem with my site that after several months of publication is not indexed.
when it was under development the box was checked to not allow indexing by search engines but once completed and moved to the definitive domain it was deactivated, but still not visible. I also had problems with the site map which was initially generated empty... then I solved it and the site domain is still not approved by google my bussines.
What could it be?
which file can I check if there is something blocking indexing?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `example.com/robots.txt`, that will show you the directives for search engine bots. You can also check the meta tags on individual pages to see if they're being blocked.

Best option would be [Google Search Console's URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289).

If the URL Inspection tool does not explain why the page is not being indexed, then try checking the page's source code for `no-index`, `no-follow`, and/or `robots`, and report back that line of code.

Comment: hello @Caleb , I looked at the robots.txt file as you recommended this and what I get  `Sitemap: https://www.example.net/wp-sitemap.xml

# START YOAST BLOCK
# ---------------------------
User-agent: *
Disallow:

# ---------------------------
# END YOAST BLOCK`

Comment: Hmm that looks right. You'll probably need to use URL Inspection tool at this point to ascertain what's happening.

Comment: hello @Caleb, yes I used the check URL tool, but it tells me that it is not indexed, I tried to click on request indexing it becomes all with green checks but then nothing changes and it returns as not indexed.  do you know what it could be because I don't see any indications here?  I also did the URL test, everything seemed fine but then nothing, the sitemap is still detected

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I only find this ```<meta name="robots" content="index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1">```

Comment: Did you try Search Console's "Test live URL"? Also try their Robots Testing Tool:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Comment: hello, i tried test live url and it gives me:
The URL is available to Google

on the other hand, on search console URL control it gives me:
The URL is not found on Google,
and send the indexing request

instead on robots testing tools it doesn't give me any error.
I can't figure out what it could be and it's been online for a few months and still can't be found

Comment: Hi, still today the site is not indexed, I have done all the recommended checks and also those of google search console but there are no problems with indexing. The URL of the site is still not approved by google business, I just can't figure out what could be causing all these problems

Comment: The proper URL for viewing the virtual (generated by WP) robots.txt is www.example.com?robots=1 . Using the URL www.example.com/robots.txt will usually get you a 404.
(This is assuming that you do not have an actual robots.txt file, which is not recommended, as it will override the WP-generated virtual file.)

Comment: @RickHellewell You are correct that internally WordPress uses `?robots=1`, but WordPress has a rewrite rule for `robots.txt`: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/44c41a52cf653a5136fc43c9f8305ec1f5d17b1f/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1283-L1285.

Comment: @Caleb : my testing indicates that www.example.com/mysite/robots.txt will return a 404. ('mysite' is the root folder of the site). If you add the '?robots=1' to any site url (with a folder as part of the site root), you will see the robots.txt file.
So - will a search engine looking for the robots.txt file at www.example.com/mysite find the virtual robots.txt file? Not sure...

Comment: @RickHellewell The code I linked to for the rewrite rule does only work if the WordPress install is at the root, which I expect is most common WordPress install scenario. WordPress installs in sub-directories will need to use `?robots=1`.

Comment: @Caleb thanks, understand. But a search engine will look for siteroot/robots.txt , so they will request www.example.com/mysite/robots.txt  . If that file doesn't exist, then will WP redirect to www.example.com/mysite/?robots=1  ? Or will the request return a 404?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if WP was capable of redirecting `robots.txt` to `?robots=1`, then I would expect the rewrite rule would not be limited to site's in root directories. So I would expect that example.com/mysite/robots.txt would return a 404. It's possible search engines know to also check `?robots=1`, but I don't know about that either.

Answer (score -1):

I Saw your previous messages from that please try some other methods like

1. Give High-Quality Backlinks to your website so Google knows your website in online.
2. Add your website link to the social media website(like facebook, insta, reddit...).

Finally, check the website from your side everything is correct try to use some online tools like -

https://www.seobility.net/en/seocheck/
https://nibbler.insites.com/
https://seositecheckup.com/tools/noindex-tag-test

Comment: hello, thanks for the advice, I tested the site with these tools that you suggested but they didn't find any serious problems other than reducing the unused css and js code, but I don't think it could be that also because I have many sites made with the same theme and no one has ever given me this kind of problem. I don't know what to try anymore from google search console I have already requested indexing several times after scanning the URL (detected suitable for the urlda google search console) which continues to be not indexed.

Comment: and besides that the url in the google my busines website field is not even approved, when i try to enter it it gets stuck loading or it says it will take some time to verify but after several days it comes back empty

Comment: Hi, still today the site is not indexed, I have done all the recommended checks and also those of google search console but there are no problems with indexing. The URL of the site is still not approved by google business, I just can't figure out what could be causing all these problems